# How to have windows automatically add an extension to a file?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter

**Background**

I am currently in the process of making a basic text editor in hopes of gaining a basic understanding of Tkinter. I want to make my own file format called `.mydoc` I have attempted to change the `filetype` to `.mydoc` to no prevail. This is the code that I currently have:

**Code**

```
def openMe(self):
    #import the Tk file dialogue
    import tkFileDialog as tkF
    myFormat = [('Example Format', '*.mydoc')]
    direct = tkF.askopenfilename(initialdir='D:\\', filetypes = myFormat, title = "Open a .mydoc")
    try:
        #open the text file
        txt_file = open(direct,"r")
    except UnboundLocalError, IOError:
        print "You either did not select a file, or the filetype was incorrect.\nPlease try again."
    #Read the data
    currentTEXT = txt_file.read()
    #Delete current text
    self.write.delete(0.0, END)
    #insert new text
    self.write.insert(0.0, currentTEXT)
```

**Question**

1. How can I have the computer automatically add my extension? (And yes, I have turned off the `hide extensions` option.

**Tech Specs**

Language: Python 2.7.3

OS: Windows 7

Comment: What is the specific error message or symptom?

Comment: @CaptainMurphy The issue is, there is no error message. I save the file, and when I go into Windows Explorer, it doesn't have an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `defaultextension`:

```
tkF.askopenfilename(initialdir='D:\\',
filetypes=myFormat,
title="Open a .mydoc",
defaultextension=".mydoc")
```